# Pivot table connected to power query is not sorting order the values in the rows of the pivot tbl

Tags: excel, powerquery

I need solution to a problem I currently encounter with my pivot table which is connected to the data source / append query using power query. Now in the power query, the append query values in the filter the data list is not in the correct order this also reflects in the pivot table.

How do I solve the below problem?

[image]

Comment: Either normalize the labels so they have the same number of digits (eg `Repair1 => Repair01`, or split the label column at the digits, and sort that column numerically.